# Spring + rest + mysql

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

**Hi friends**,
        I am new to spring frame work, please help me to create simple web serice application using **spring frameWork+ Mysql database+restFul** web services and how i can perform **CURD** opreations using restFul API's, from restClient please help from basic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty decent tutorial on getting started with Spring MVC: http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

For mysql, have a look at: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/

Answer (score 2):

GOto https://github.com/JohnathanMarkSmith Johnathan Smith has examples for that and if you need his help he is always willing to help